# Geometric Network Error

Tags: arccatalog, geometric-network

[image]

May I know where I made a mistake?

I have already referred to the following link:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n0000000r000000
 and I have also attached an example image to show the problem.

Comment: Please always provide errors as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches and easily read on all devices.

Answer (score 4):

There are errors that one can get due to several wrong bits. Please refer to the help page [Identifying geometric network build errors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002r0000000z000000). Most often these errors have to do something with errors in features' geometry.

I would start with:

1) Click Customize > Toolbars > Geometric Network Editing.
The Geometric Network Editing toolbar is added to ArcMap.

2) Add your network feature classes to ArcMap.

3) On the Editor toolbar, click Editor > Start Editing. In the ArcMap table of contents, select a layer that participates in the geometric network.

4) Click the Network Build Errors command. A dialog box indicating the number of errors is displayed, and the features with illegal geometries are selected.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Alex, May I know how can i enable Geometric Network Editing tool? After I did start editing that tool was disabled.